# How do I keep date order after using the split function in R?

Tags: r, sorting, date

I have a csv which is has a list of lat-long coordinates with dates for each. I have code to split the data by date

```
X <- split(mydata, mydata$date)
```

But when I run the function the data is sorted numerically rather than by date. So for example this:

```
  long       lat       date
 26.71360 -31.67479 04-04-2013
 26.53347 -31.54144 05-04-2013
 26.36730 -31.39950 06-04-2013
 26.15438 -31.27452 04-05-2013
 26.25447 -31.06523 04-05-2013
 26.31591 -30.92225 04-05-2013
```

Would be converted to this: Note that dates are d/m/y

```
long       lat       date
 26.71360 -31.67479 04-04-2013
 26.53347 -31.54144 04-05-2013
 26.36730 -31.39950 04-05-2013
 26.15438 -31.27452 04-05-2013
 26.25447 -31.06523 05-04-2013
 26.31591 -30.92225 06-04-2013
```

How can I keep the order?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Please check these links about general ideas of a reproducible example and how to producce one in R: [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that your 'date' variable is of class `Date`. Conversion from `character` to `Date` representations of dates can be made with `as.Date`. Because the format of your input dates is neither `"%Y-%m-%d"` nor `"%Y/%m/%d"` (see `format` argument in `?as.Date`) you need to specify `format` explicitly. See `?strptime` for abbreviations of the various time components.

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
```